# Batch in SQL Server recursion

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to run recursion for set of arguments in relation employee-manager

each employee is assigned to some manager, and each manager can be assigned to another manager ... ∞

my database:

```
id  name       report_to
1   CEO        null 
2   frank      1 
3   john       2 
4   CTO        null
5   ana        4
6   candy      5
```

Simple recursion subtree for single argument CEO:

```
with recursive employee_sub_tree as 
(
   select id,
          name,
          report_to
   from category
   where name = 'CEO'  -- this defines the start of the recursion
   union all
   select child.id,
          child.name,
          child.report_to
   from employee as child
     join employee_sub_tree as parent on parent.id = child.report_to -- the self join to report to manager
)
select *
from employee_sub_tree
```

result:

```
1   CEO        null
2   frank      1 
3   john       2
```

result for query with condition name in ('CEO', 'CTO'):

```
id  name       report_to
1   CEO        null 
2   frank      1 
3   john       2 
4   CTO        null
5   ana        4
6   candy      5
```

in above I have all desired records, but I lost information about who is top level manager:

I am looking for sql which will return for me result:

```
top_level_report_to  id  name       report_to
CEO                  1   CEO        null 
CEO                  2   frank      1 
CEO                  3   john       2 
CTO                  4   CTO        null
CTO                  5   ana        4
CTO                  6   candy      5
```

Very important that it must be 1 query as sometimes i am looking for result of several top level managers

Answer (score 1):

Include the original name as another column and aggregate in the end:

```
with recursive sub_tree as (
      select id, name, parent_category, name as orig_name
      from category
      where name in ( 'X', 'Y' )  -- this defines the start of the recursion
      union all
      select child.id, child.name, child.parent_category, sub_tree.orig_name
      from category child join
           sub_tree parent
           on parent.id = child.parent_category -- the self join to the CTE builds up the recursion
    )
select orig_name, count(*)
from sub_tree
group by orig_name;
```

I don't know what you mean by "sum of their results" so this just illustrates a count.